# Positively invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

> What is the difference between "Positively invariant subspace" and "Invariant subspace" (with respect to a linear operator)?

I know the second concept and just found the first online.
No meaningful explanation show up in the search engine for the first.

Comment: "Positively invariant subspace" doesn't have much in the way of useful Google results, but "positively invariant" by itself does. In particular, there's the Wikipedia page for [positively invariant sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positively_invariant_set). (The context for 'positively invariant' is the of nonlinear systems, which seems to match up with the usage for 'positively invariant subspace' in the Google results.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I discarded the link on "sets" that you mentioned. My error. The document I'm reading speaks of powers of $(\phi-\lambda)$, thus once a vector enter a mentioned subspace $W$ then by increasing $k$ in $(\phi-\lambda)^k$ it will never leave the subspace $W$.